# routing from multiple NICs having the same address

Tags: routing, linux-networking, dhcp

I tried this question on NetworkEngineering StackExchange and they rejected, referring me to Serverfault. Serverfault rejected an earlier version of this, referring me to StackExchange. It's time to stop passing the buck. This is a real question about a real network admin setting. 
 https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59210/routing-with-multiple-nics-connected-to-multiple-aps-that-were-all-assigned-th?noredirect=1#comment104630_59210

The situation:

I have 4 wireless APs based on the ESP8266. These APs all broadcast distinct SSIDs, but each serves LAN addresses in subnet 192.168.4.XXX. The subnet value is not configurable.

Then, I have a Linux host with 4 wireless NICs. I can make each NIC connect as a client of a different AP. NIC#1 one is connected to AP#1 ... NIC#4 is connected to AP#4. Because all APs serve up .4 addresses, there is a chance that all 4 NIC will get assigned the same IP, e.g. all 4 NICs might be assigned 192.168.4.101.

Each of the APs has other devices connected to them, besides the dedicated host NIC. All devices are given addresses on the .4 network. For example, there might be a printer on AP#2 with IP 192.168.4.102 and a scanner connected to AP#4 also with IP 192.168.4.102.

The question:

Is there any way that networking on the Linux host can be made to work?

Specifically in the above example, how might one address (read data from/write data to) the printer versus the scanner?

Thanks, Bilal

Comment: `Is there any way that networking on the Linux host can be made to work` - Short answer, probably not.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the Linux host, nor with the printer and scanner. If you have four APs that serve up DHCP addresses from overlapping (or identical) ranges, and the APs don't mutually communicate to avoid giving out the same address twice, you'll never be able to get robust communication. I suggest you talk to the AP vendor and figure out if they have a way to 1) get them to each use a different DHCP pool, or 2) get them to communicate with each other to not give out an address that is already in use, or 3) have them delegate the DHCP function to a separate DHCP server.

Comment: @DougDeden That would be fine as an answer... @ BilalKhan ... and it's probably the only answer possible.